# Requests failing with a timeout, why?

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I have configured MassTransit with RabbitMQ as transport. And I just use an instance of generic IRequestClient to send requests to a consumer that then should return a response.

My problem is that every other request fails with a TimeoutException. Execute it once, the next time it fails, and then it works again.

The Consumer is not even invoked when failed.

What can be the reason for this?

I have other services share a similar name in their requests and consumers. I have tried to figure out if that is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You should post the configuration code of your application using the request client and the one configuring the consumer.

If you have other consumers with the same name, it's likely they're on the same queue if you're using `ConfigureEndpoints`, which could be the root cause of the issue.

Since it's every-other-message that times out, that would make sense since RabbitMQ will load balance the queue across the different services with the same queue name.

Comment: OK. Consumers in different services share the same name. They share the same queues. I can verify. Now, I have to figure out how to differentiate them by name.

services.AddMassTransit(x =>
            {
                x.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();
                x.AddConsumers(typeof(Program).Assembly);
                x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
                {
                    cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
                });
            });
            services.AddMassTransitHostedService();

Comment: There are options on the endpoint name formatter constructor to add namespace, if that helps.

Comment: OK. Perhaps, in this case, I should instead try to give my requests and notifications unique names that tell what they are about - then I would not have the conflict. I will try this first. Thank you!

Comment: You should definitely _not_ be using the same message types for unrelated consumers. And distinct consumer and saga names are always recommended.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense now. My theory from before asking this question proved right. And I have fixed this so it now works in practice again. It all started because I copied projects, and you know... naming. Now I have AddOrderItem* and AddCartItem* respectively. My test project.